# Change any string to string with specific size

Tags: c#, string

I have strings like these:

```
azu3zS1YdQBF75qmp4oyi1/ttG6/ikOSkZZCdgAYGw2x8A4YBILnZ6lOhIRNgQJEcH56pqnrb8Y=
```

and I do not know the exact length of them so I want a function to change any strinng to a string of 20 characters.

Comment: Have you ever look `Substring` method?

Comment: Take the substring ranging from 0 to the minimum between the length of the string and 20

Comment: i want something that i can get back the original string not lose them

Comment: @amirbt You don't lose anything. Strings are immutable. String functions always return a new string.

Comment: thanks a lot Substring work how could i get back the original String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var x= str== null 
        ? string.Empty 
        : str.Substring(0, Math.Min(20, str.Length));
```

Comment: thanks a lot Substring work how could i get back the original String

Comment: @amirbt your original string will remain same in `str`

Comment: @amirbt you don't need to get it back.  It is still stored in the `str` variable, while the `x` variable holds the newly-created substring.  (Or if the original string's length was 20 characters or fewer, then both variables point to the same string instance.)

Comment: @phoog Are you sure it will point to the same instance if length is same?

Comment: @Shaharyar i know i have str i dont have access to str because the customer gives me the substring over the phone or internet and i should get back the original string from Substring

Comment: @amirbt That is another scenario. We don't even know your system architecture/workflow.

Comment: @Shaharyar I am, but that's an implementation detail, so you should not rely on it.  See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,1270

Comment: @Rahul, +1 for Math.Min(... I've been using if conditions to check for that. thanks.

Comment: @Shaharyar i just want to get back the original str from substring and it is windows Form application is there anyway or i should try other things

Answer (score -1):

string a = "get the first 20 characters";
 a = a.Substring(0, 20);

Comment: Substring is zero-based. You will lose the first character